# Extracción de columna de un csv con DictReader y desviación estandar con numpy

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy

Estoy con un ejercicio de extracción de una columna de un csv bastante grande con DictReader para después convertirlo en np.array y hallar la desviación estandar, lo pensaba bastante fácil, pero no, me da error, he hecho esto

```
fichero=csv.DictReader(open('bicis_examen.csv',encoding='utf'))
lista_bicis=[]
for row in fichero:
    lista_bicis.append(row['available_bikes'])
bicis_disponibles=np.array(lista_bicis)
print('La desviación estandar de la columna available bikes es',np.std(bicis_disponibles))
```

Y el error que me da es el siguiente:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradezco

Comment: Posiblemente la columna `available_bikes`  no sea numérica, revisa la importación, lo mejor es solucionarlo de entrada, sino prueba algo así: `bicis_disponibles=np.array(lista_bicis).astype(np.float)` antes de calcular la desciación estándar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esa línea se ha arreglado, un saludo

Answer (score 1):

El problema seguramente se debe a que la importación dejo la columna como cadena y no como un tipo numérico. Esto seguramente se podría solucionar ajustando la importación, pero sin conocer como es el archivo, difícil dar una consejo. De cualquier forma puedes convertir el tipo de la columna de interés para luego aplicar la desviación estándar:

```
bicis_disponibles=np.array(lista_bicis).astype(np.float
```

De todas formas, pe parece que te estas complicando la vida, si ya estás usando `numpy` seguramente también estés usando `pandas`, por lo que leer el `csv` es mucho más simple y el acceso a una columna en particular no requiere del ciclo que estás haciendo:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('bicis_examen.csv') 
print('La desviación estandar de la columna available bikes es', data[['available_bikes']].std())
```

Nota: de todas formas hay que revisar que la columna luego de importada sea numérica.